# Laradock - add custom npm package

Tags: node.js, laravel, docker, npm, dockerfile

It's a kind of not normal thing, but this is something, that temporarily is a solution.
I have laradock installed in a system and laravel app.

All that I'm using from laradock provides me command below

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql php-worker workspace redis
```

I need to add node package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiktok-scraper) installed globally in my docker, so I can get results by executing php code like below

```
exec('tiktok-scraper user username-n 3 -t json');
```

This needs to be available for php-fpm and php-worker level, as I need this in jobs and for endpoints, that should invoke scrape.

I know, that I'm doing wrong, but I have tried to install it within workspace like using

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
npm i -g tiktok-scraper
```

and after this it's available in my workspace (I can run for instance `tiktok-scraper --help`) and it will show me the different options.

But this doesn't solve the issue, as I'm getting nothing by `exec('tiktok-scraper user username-n 3 -t json');` in my laravel app.

I'm not so familiar with docker and not sure, in which dockerfile should I put something like

```
RUN npm i -g tiktok-scraper
```

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute the npm package from inside your php-worker you would need to install it in the php-worker container. But for the php exec() to have an effect on your workspace this workspace would need to be in the same container as your php-worker.

Comment: If to have this installed in php-worker container, it will be enough I guess to be able to execute from queued jobs and in direct api request endpoints, correct ?

Comment: To make this work for php-worker and for php-fpm, I have to add them in both containers dockerfile, so this mainly a correct answer.